# Spring controller throwing HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED fires 500 Http error instead of 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

Here's the scenario :
I created the following custom response exception, to fire the 401 Http Status :

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class HttpUnauthorizedException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

The controller that uses the exception :

```
@Controller
public UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/user")
    @ResponseBody

    public String doLogin(
                 @RequestParam(value = "username", required = false) String username, @RequestParam(value = "password", required = false) String password) {
        if(userLoggedIn(String username, String password)) {
             return "OK";
        }
        else {
             throw new HttpUnauthorizedException();
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Now when I try to access the controller to see the 401 exception, the server fires the Http error code 500 instead. But interestingly enough, when I try with the `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` it actually works, the server fires 404. Is there something I'm missing on here?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First `throw new HttpUnauthorizedException();`

then you can catch it at a normal controller that have `@ControllerAdvice` annotation

```
@ControllerAdvice // To Handle Exceptions
public class ExceptionController {
     //// ...........

     @ExceptionHandler({HttpUnauthorizedException.class})
     @ResponseBody
     @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
     Map<String, String> unauthorizedAccess(Exception e) {
         Map<String, String> exception = new HashMap<String, String>();

         log.error("unauthorized Access to the API: " + e.getMessage(), e);
         exception.put("code", "401");
         exception.put("reason", e.getMessage());

         return exception;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think code should be much simpler, maybe the answer was written with old Spring version.

In this example I've implemented method to handle exception - **HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized** to cover authentication issue (401):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorsHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAuthenticationError(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request)
    {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, 
            "Cannot login, please check your inputs", 
            new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, request);
    }
}
```

Finally I get correct error to GUI

[image: Login failure presentation]

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class UnauthorizedException extends RuntimeException{
  
}
```

Controller:

```
import ....authentication.exception.UnauthorizedException;

@SecurityRequirement(name = "JWTBearerAuth")
@GetMapping(value = "/name/{name}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Users getUserByName(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @PathVariable("name") String name) throws Exception {

    if (condition) {
      final Users users = usersService.getUserByName(name);
      return users;
    } else {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    } 
  }
```

This works for me.